# Git order of operations

Tags: git, github

I am working (alone) on a repository. I have the repository in GitHub and locally in my computer. Currently, I have three branches: features, develop and main. I'm making some changes on the features branch right now and I was wondering if the way I've been approaching this is correct.

Normally (if I'm working on the features branch), I would commit my changes, then push to the remote repository, then merge features into develop and then push develop. But I was wondering if it matters if I, instead, commit my changes, then merge with develop and then push twice (one push for features and one push for develop)? Is it the same? Or is the a difference between these two workflows? What is the "typical" one?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The order in which these operations is performed does not matter.  That is to say, you are doing three things: merging one branch (`target`) into another (`current`); pushing `target`; and pushing `current`.  Of course it makes a difference to merge before pushing `current` (because merging `target` into `current` advances `current`, either by fast-forward to `target`, or onto a merge commit that combines `target` with `current`) - but both of your proposed workflows do that.

So the question is the order of pushing `target`, and merging `target` into `current`.  Neither of these operations affects the other in any material way, so it doesn't matter.

Were you working with a team, you might have to sort out some team standards on branching and merging workflow.  Even then this detail would be insignificant as long as no steps were totally forgotten, but you'd want to make sure everyone agreed on what is or is not ok.

Also, if you used a `rebase`-based workflow instead of a `merge`-based workflow, it could matter, because you generally should avoid doing a rebase that removes from a branch commits that have already been pushed on that branch.

But if you're working alone (so the only "team" you have to coordinate with is yourself) and doing merges (so history is not routinely rewritten), it doesn't matter and no one way is "more typical" or "more correct".

Comment: I guess here: "So the question is the order of pushing target, and merging target into current" you missed the pushing of current too? Or were you assuming the current was already pushed?

Answer (score 0):

Or do your work locally however is convenient and push whatever's ready whenever it's time.  If you do the feature work and the merge, then you can `git push origin feature develop`.  The only typical order is, you push to publish, and you publish what's ready.

---

Stop thinking of two repos being the same.  Histories can be the same, and exist in any number of repos, but repo boundaries are ephemeral.  Your two repos are already wildly different, if you're anything like me your local repo has experimental branches, WIP stuff that's wildly broken that will be cleaned up with a nice `rebase -i` before anybody else ever sees it, la la. None of that belongs in a published repo.

You can even carry multiple histories in a repo, mix and match as you like.  Once you're comfortable with Git you can carry your submodule histories in your main repo, for instance; that makes small-ish utility libraries vastly more convenient to work with, here's a clip from a makefile:

```
setup:  utils/.git

utils/.git:
    @if _=`git rev-parse -q --verify utils`; then \
        git config submodule.utils.active true \
        && git config submodule.utils.url "`pwd -P`" \
        && git clone -s . utils -nb utils \
        && git submodule --quiet absorbgitdirs utils \
        && git -C utils checkout $$(git rev-parse :utils); \
    fi
```

(fix markdown's tab damage) and I carry a `utils` history with related projects.  If it got bigger, like gnulib size, I'd just do my clones `--reference` a known-history depot for it, then there'd only be one copy on disk for like 99% of it.  But this is getting way ahead of the game, suffice it to say that if I fix or tweak a utility it's easy, do it right where it's immediately useful and publish it wherever it's needed, you can find all repos carrying a history with e.g.

```
root=(`git rev-list --max-parents=0 heads/utils`)
find $projects -name objects -execdir git cat-file -e $root \; -printf %h\\n
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.  Those are all things that you can do with a repo, but they are not the use case OP is asking about.

Comment: So, "The only typical order is, you push to publish, and you publish what's ready" doesn't answer ~what's a typical order~?  I think it does.

Comment: @jhill - No, it does not.  Cherry-picking words that sound similar does not change the fact that you didn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using GitHub, and the flow is that work done in the `features` branch should at some later point be brought into the `develop` branch, then one common workflow would be to use a pull request in GitHub.

You would complete your work in the `features` branch, then push to GitHub.  From GitHub web, you may create a pull request with `develop` as a destination.  Other may review your work in the pull request, leave comments, etc.  Once the pull request is approved, someone may merge it into `develop`.  At this point, your work in `features` should not be in both branches.

Comment: OP is asking a direct question about comparing two workflows (not answered here).  Instead this answer recommends a third workflow that depends on tools we don't know OP is using, and that balances costs and benefits in a way that makes sense for teams (whereas OP mentioned they are working alone).